# Método e SubPrograma

Tags: funções, terminologia, método

Ambos significam a mesma coisa?

```
void subrotina(){};
```

Isso não é chamado método também? As pessoas não falam que vão fazer um subprograma que faz algo, normalmente as pessoas falam: "vo fazer um metodo que faz algo.".

Answer (score 1):

Em programação orientada a objectos esses *subprogramas* chamam-se métodos e podem retornar ou não valores. Em programação estruturada esses *subprogramas* chamam-se funções quando retornam alguma coisa e procedimentos quando não retornam nada, como é o caso desse seu método *subrotina* que tem a palavra chave **void**

Por convensão escreve-se o nome dos métodos com letra pequena e caso sejam duas palavras usa-se letra maiúcula na primeira letra da segunda palavra.

Ex: getWidth()

Esta prática de escrita designa-se como *lowerCamelCase*

Answer (score 0):

Tudo a mesma coisa. Da [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subroutine):

> In different programming languages a subroutine may be called a procedure, a function, a routine, a method, or a subprogram. The generic term callable unit is sometimes used.

Traduzindo: "Em diferentes linguagens de programacao uma subrotina pode ser chamada de procedimento, funcao, rotina, metodo ou subprograma. O termo generico unidade invocavel e as vezes utilizado" (traducao livre).